# How do I remove a game object from a list of game objects where each gameobject is an instantiated 'piece' or a class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I recently started learning to make unity games and I have come across this issue that I haven't able to fix:

I created a class called `piece`. `pieces` is a 2d array of piece classes.
Then I created a list of Game Objects called `activepiece`.

To add to the list, I instantiated a game object and added it to the list as follows:

```
GameObject go = Instantiate(piecePrefab[index],GetTileCenter(x,y),Quaternion.identity) as GameObject; 
go.transform.SetParent (transform);
pieces[x,y] = go.GetComponent<piece>();
pieces[x,y].SetPosition (x,y);
activepiece.Add (go);
```

Now the issue comes with removing a certain/specific piece from the list, which I try to do as follows:

```
piece c = pieces[x,y];
if(c != null){
    activepiece.Remove(c.GameObject);
    Destroy(c.GameObject);    
}
```

I come upon this error from Unity:

> error CS1061: 'piece' does not contain a definition for 'GameObject' and no accessible extension method 'GameObject' accepting a first argument of type 'piece' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: have you tried c.gameObject, with a lowercase g?

Comment: Note that instantiated game objects are of type `GameObject`, not `Piece`. `Piece` is a component attached *to* the game object.

Comment: Also, can you show your `Piece` class?

Comment: @Dracos18s Hey thanks for the input , I fixed my code up to find all gameobjects with that certain piece component and remove the gameobject from the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution though I'm sure this isnt elegant in any fashion :

```
piece c = pieces[x,y]; 
GameObject k = activepiece.Find(g => g.GetComponent<piece>() == c);
activepiece.Remove(k);
Destroy(k);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are you sure your array contains the piece?

If it does, try this(if you haven't):

```
piece c = pieces[x,y];
if(c != null){   
    activepiece.Remove(c.GameObject);
    Destroy(c.gameObject);  
}
```